# Preventing Spark HiveContext from connecting to Hive

Tags: azure, apache-spark, hive, azure-hdinsight

I'm using the `HiveContext` in Apache Spark 1.3, because I need its better query support (vs 1.3's `SQLContext`).

I'm running on an Azure 'HDInsight' Spark cluster. The driver's HiveContext is trying to connect to a nonexistent Hive metastore. This is breaking the driver.

I don't actually need Hive support at all.

What's the best way to **stop Spark's HiveContext trying to connect to Hive**? eg, unset particular environment properties? (There are 100s of possibly-related preset properties).

---

**Edit** Stacktrace:

```
15/10/14 06:35:29 WARN metastore: Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
15/10/14 06:35:50 WARN metastore: Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
15/10/14 06:36:11 WARN metastore: Failed to connect to the MetaStore Server...
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:346)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.sessionState$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:241)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.sessionState(HiveContext.scala:237)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$QueryExecution.<init>(HiveContext.scala:385)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executePlan(HiveContext.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executePlan(HiveContext.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$.apply(DataFrame.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.load(SQLContext.scala:728)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.jsonFile(SQLContext.scala:564)
        ..<snip>..
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:577)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:174)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1412)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:62)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2453)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2465)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:340)
        ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1410)
        ... 52 more
Caused by: MetaException(message:Could not connect to meta store using any of the URIs provided. Most recent failure: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException:
connect timed out
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:185)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.open(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:336)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:214)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1410)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:62)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:72)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2453)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2465)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:340)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.sessionState$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:241)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.sessionState(HiveContext.scala:237)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$QueryExecution.<init>(HiveContext.scala:385)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executePlan(HiveContext.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executePlan(HiveContext.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.<init>(DataFrame.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$.apply(DataFrame.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.load(SQLContext.scala:728)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.jsonFile(SQLContext.scala:564)
        ..<snip>..
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:577)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:174)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:180)
        ... 59 more
)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.open(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:382)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:214)
        ... 57 more
```

Answer (score 2):

The relevant property is `hive.metastore.uris`.

It was preset to `thrift://headnodehost:9083` due to the preloaded `C:\apps\dist\spark-1.3.1.2.2.7.1-0004\hive-site.xml`. This was earlier in the generated CLASSPATH than my own `hive-site.xml` which was being ignored.

I couldn't find a simple working way to override that property value. (If you know a way, please comment)

As a hack solution, I just moved that `hive-site.xml` out of the way. Of course this must be done manually through RDP (which you must enable on your headnode).